# WebService authentication via default MembershipProvider

Tags: c#, wcf, security, forms-authentication

What is the best practice when you need to authenticate specific `OperationContracts`, while using the default `MembershipProvider` for security (`FormsAuthentication`).

I guess that doing `Membership.ValidateUser` and `Membership.GetUser` just won't cut it when using WebServices, right?

In other words: How can I verify that a user is allowed to use specific methods in the webservice (that the user is authenticated/"logged on")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah--you can't really use `FormsAuthentication` in this case. But there is excellent infrastructure available in WCF for managing role-based access to individual methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have been known to over-engineer things, so when I use WCF in my web applications, I wrap the service in my web app.  This way my web app calls the abstraction.

Now, what you can do is apply your code access security (CAS) on the wrapper.

Example code might look like this (tons of details omitted for brevity)

```
internal class ServiceWrapper
{
    Service Svc;
    public ServiceWrapper()
    {
        Svc = ServiceClient();
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "HelloWorld")]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return Svc.HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

In a perfect world, we would want CAS to be a bit more dry (don't repeat yourself), meaning handled in the WCF as you suggest.  But this might be a good middle of the road if know you can lock down your WCF app and control who calls it :-)

That would help you simplify getting the ball rolling...

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, but how would you do the authentication part? So that the caller gets authenticated, that is.

Comment: My example *assumes* you already have forms authentication setup and a role provider in place.  The PrincipalPermission attribute on a method as shown in my example basically performs a check of HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(RoleName) and if the result is false, it will throw a SecurityException.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx